# Safari Json.stringify error

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, safari

Im getting this error (**Only Safari**, Chrome and Firefox is working) : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'params' on the function:

```
  function buildprojecttypeselect(params){
  var result;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "include/builds/buildprojecttypeselect.php",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({params}),
    success: function(data) {
       result = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
  });

return result;

}
```

something is wrong with the json.stringify({params}).

params is an a array =

```
[Object { 0="2",  1="name1",  id_projecttype="2"}, 
Object { 0="3",  1="name2",  id_projecttype="3"}, 
Object { 0="4",  1="nam3",  id_projecttype="4"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the braces around `params`:

```
  function buildprojecttypeselect(params){
  var result;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "include/builds/buildprojecttypeselect.php",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    success: function(data) {
       result = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
  });

return result;

}
```